# Standardizing date strings with different time zones in python

Tags: python, date

I have date strings that look like this `Tue Aug 03 2021 18:25:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` or `Mon Aug 23 2021 21:51:35 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)`

I'm attempting to convert them into a standard format and then update the timezones to UTC.

I'm able to do a bit of parsing and get a result like `2021-08-03 18:25:34+05:30`.

My question is how to I then convert `2021-08-03 18:25:34+05:30` to UTC? My desired result would be subtracting 5.5 hours and removing the utc offset portion of the timestamp to get something like `2021-08-03 12:55:34`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but, that timestamp tells you it is 5:30 hours /ahead/ of UTC, to so need to subtract it, not add it. If you want a formal standard, search for ISO 8601. It's close, just not quite there.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited to clarify the question bit. Do you know the best way to subtract the 5.5 hours? I can think of an ugly way but am unsure if there's something better.

Comment: The [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object can be created from hours, minutes and seconds directly, then added or subtracted from a `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: Why not just add a T and make it ISO 8601 format and then use one of these two to parse the string ?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html fromISOformat method
 or https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse  Then use astimezone(timezone.utc) to get the UTC time.